# Different memory usage between compiled typescript and vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mqtt

When I compile my typescript code, which is exactly the same as the vanilla javascript code, I get an increase in memory usage while the code is running up until it crashes. The vanilla javascript code memory usage stays the same the whole time.

The code connects to an mqtt broker, then reads in a file and publishes each line in the file as mqtt message.

**Typescript code:**

```js
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
import { split, mapSync } from 'event-stream'
import { connect } from 'mqtt'

const client = connect('mqtt://localhost:1883')

client.on('connect', () => {
  let lineNr = 0
  const stream = createReadStream('<PATH_TO_LARGE_FILE>')
    .pipe(split())
    .pipe(mapSync(async line => {

      // pause the readstream
      stream.pause()

      lineNr++

      if(lineNr % 1000 === 0)
        console.log(`${lineNr}\t${process.memoryUsage().heapTotal / 1048576}`)


      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.publish('/standardized', line.toString(), () => {
          resolve()
        })
      })

      stream.resume()
    })
      .on('error', function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file.', err)
        stream.destroy()
      })
      .on('end', function(){
        console.log('Read entire file')
        stream.destroy()
      })
    )
})
```

**Vanilla Javascript:**

```
const { createReadStream } = require('fs')
const { split, mapSync } = require('event-stream')
const { connect } = require('mqtt')

const client = connect('mqtt://localhost:1883')

client.on('connect', () => {
  let lineNr = 0
  const stream = createReadStream('<PATH_TO_LARGE_FILE>')
    .pipe(split())
    .pipe(mapSync(async line => {

      // pause the readstream
      stream.pause()

      lineNr++

      if(lineNr % 1000 === 0)
        console.log(`${lineNr}\t${process.memoryUsage().heapTotal / 1048576}`)


      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.publish('/standardized', line.toString(), () => {
          resolve()
        })
      })

      stream.resume()
    })
      .on('error', function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file.', err)
        stream.destroy()
      })
      .on('end', function(){
        console.log('Read entire file')
        stream.destroy()
      })
    )
})
```

Expected: the memory usage should stay the same for the compiled typescript code as well
Actual: the memory usage for the compiled typescript code increases up until the code crashes

Comment: Have you checked the generated JavaScript code (the code that the Typescript transpiler writes) for differences?

Comment: As @Pointy says, compare the compiled TypeScript with the vanilla JavaScript. With a modern target the compiled TypeScript looks almost identical to your JavaScript. So my guess is you're using an "old" target which doesn't support async/await meaning TypeScript injects a polyfill that uses more memory.

Comment: If you by any chance use something like `ts-node` or some other way to compile you ts at runtime, then this might be the reason for your problem. Then the first thing you should do is to compile your ts manually and use the resulting js directly to see if the memory is still leaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, it was indeed a "wrong" tsconfig (had target: "es6" in it, changed it to "ESNext"). Thanks all for the comments!